# Castle Windsor dispose order

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor

I have a problem with dispose order of resolved components using Windsor Castle. The issue can be demonstrated on the following code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer())
        {
            container.Register(Component.For<C1>().LifestyleSingleton());
            container.Register(Component.For<C2>().LifestyleTransient());
            C1 c1 = container.Resolve<C1>();
            container.Release(c1);
            Console.WriteLine("Release done");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Container dispose done");
    }
}

public class C1 : IDisposable
{
    private C2 m_c2;

    public C1(C2 c2)
    {
        m_c2 = c2;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose C1");
    }
}

public class C2 : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose C2");
    }
}
```

It prints out following:

```
Release done
Dispose C2
Dispose C1
Dispose C2
Container dispose done
```

I would expect following output:

```
Release done
Dispose C1
Dispose C2
Container dispose done
```

Disposing C2 before C1 can cause serious problem in C1. C1 can still be alive and be processing something. Note that problem disappears when both components are registered with LifestyleSingleton or LifestyleTransient but there still exist cases where registering C2 as LifestyleTransient can be useful.

Is there a way to register or resolve components to solve this problem?

Comment: According to [this oldish answer by Krzysztof himself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3334449/1698557) releasing singletons doesn't actually do anything, so those output statements are probably coming from the disposal of the container.  Does that change anything for you?  You could add a few more `WriteLine` calls to verify this.

Comment: Seems odd to have something with a lifestyle of singleton have a dependency on something transient. Can you not register `C2` twice, once (default) transient, and a second time as singleton, and then have `C1` be dependent on the singleton registration?

Comment: You explicitly release C1. How is it possible that it "can still be alive and be processing something"? Surely you would not have released it if that were the case.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I have updated the sample to clearly demonstrate when the relase happens. As Patrick has mentioned for singletons it happens when disposing the container. However it does not solve the problem, with this behavior problems can still occure when closing the application. Damien_The_Unbeliever solution would work with named components for C2 with different lifestyles. But I still think its only a workaround to already existing problem with dispose order. Furthermore there should not be a reason to call C2 Dispose twice.

Comment: It is still not clear what the problem is. You state that the output is not what you expect but why do you expect that output? Even if there were valid reason for your expectations, I cannot see any problem that would arise from your expectations not being met.

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt I believe that the fact he is releasing the resolved interface does not relate to the fact that the actual compoonent has done its processing. The lifetime of the component is determined by its lifestyle, that in case of singleton lifestyle means that the object "lives" until it is Disposed by the Windsor container. If the Dispose order is incorrect and the component is actively working (possibly on different thread) until it is disposed, the component might access a disposed dependency component during that work.

Comment: Whether the actual disposal of C1 occurs when he calls Release(c1) or when he disposes the container seems irrelevant. The point is that both these actions are imperatively triggered by his code - why would you Release an object if it is still in use?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using a scope and register C1 as Scoped. In this case, the dispose order is correct. But I'm not sure if this is the recommended way.