# Windsor Container LifeStyle issue

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Has anyone  observed this bug with Windsor container, This is a example of the problem that i am facing. Class A Implements Interface I, and both A & I are registered with the container as Singleton. During application Load 'class A' is resolved and some processing is done. During the application log out the container instance is disposed off.
when we log in to the same application again and when 'class A' gets resolved we still get the same object that was resolved before the container was disposed. This was reconfirmed many times by comparing the Hashcode of the object.

This seems to be issue and really do not understand logically how the same object if returned even if container object is set to null in the dispose method.

Look forward to a reasonable logic from other great minds.

Comment: interesting! I guess you might expect the context to 'remove' the singleton, but equally a 'true' singleton cant be removed

Comment: well the manual for CW does say it will be "The sole instance will be released when the container it's registered with is disposed" so I guess its a bug. But! should you really be using a singleton when your app needs more than one version?

Comment: although I note you say "container object is set to null" do you actualy call the dispose method on the container?

Comment: Please post the code that allows us to reproduce this. My first impression is that you are doing something wrong, but without the code there's no way for us to verify nor give any feedback.

Comment: Suresh, did you have a chance to go back to your code and check your assertions regarding the release/dispose problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaking releasing and disposing. You cannot release a singleton, it lives with your container until the container itself gives up (ie is disposed).

However disposing of the container do force the singleton to be resolved again. Here is some code I tried

```
namespace WindsorTest
{
    public interface ISingleton  {}

    public class Singleton : ISingleton
    {
        public static int instance = 0;
        public Singleton() { Console.WriteLine("I live anew as instance {0}", instance++); }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TheCircleOfLife(false);
            TheCircleOfLife(true);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void TheCircleOfLife(bool disposeBetweenReleases)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I {0}dispose between resolves", disposeBetweenReleases ? "" : "don't ");
            var container = new WindsorContainer();
            container.Register(Component.For<ISingleton>().ImplementedBy<Singleton>().LifestyleSingleton());
            ISingleton singleton = container.Resolve<ISingleton>();
            container.Release(singleton);
            if (disposeBetweenReleases) container.Dispose();
            singleton = container.Resolve<ISingleton>();
            container.Release(singleton);
        }
    } 
}
```

And here is the output

```
I don't dispose between resolves
I live anew as instance 0
I dispose between resolves
I live anew as instance 1
I live anew as instance 2
```

As far as I can see this is not a bug: releasing a singleton doesn't do anything since the singleton lives in a global state([here it is said again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3334449/3204) by somebody much more believable than me :) ), only the container disposal forces a new resolution.

If you need a lifetime that is linked to the user session, maybe you should investigate [custom lifecycles](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Lifecycle&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) instead of a singleton that doesn't match your needs

Comment: Hi, Firstly thanks a ton for the valuable time to investigate and respond. The singleton state is specific to container life cycle if i understand correctly, so when the container gets disposed this also should return a new singleton instance. This is providing me the object that was created before the container was disposed.

Comment: @SureshSharma Could you show an example of what you are saying? I didn't observe this during this test